# Resizing div when integer is at a certain number

Tags: javascript, css

I am having trouble to resize my div when `var i` reaches 100. Here's my code:

```
switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 38:
                i++;
                document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = i;
                if (i > 99) {
                    document.getElementById('score').style.width = '700px'
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('score').style.width = '500px'
                }
            break;
}
```

Comment: `i>99` instead of `s>99` ?

Comment: Still doesnt work, thanks though

Comment: have you tried consoling the output in the if bracket? does it even go there?

Comment: It works now, it was a typo in the css file *facepalm*

Comment: As always, please post **all** the relevant code (HTML, CSS and JavaScript) and place it all into a "code snippet" in your question so that we can have an executable version of your code and reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're providing works fine, so the problem is elsewhere. I've made a snippet (but with the button being the space bar, and the width changing at 10 iterations not 100). It works fine, so maybe show us more of your code:

```js
var i = 0;

document.onkeypress = function(event) {

   switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 32:
          i++;
          document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = i;
          if (i > 9) {
               document.getElementById('score').style.width = '200px'
             } else {
               document.getElementById('score').style.width = '100px'
             }
          break;
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="score" style="width:100px; background:red">0</div>
```